# Пробел или &nbsp; в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка:

```
<span itemprop="ratingCount">32 680</span>
```

Мне нужно получить

```
ratingCount">36 345
```

Делаю

```
#ratingCount\"\>(\w*)*(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(\w*)#
```

Получаю

```
ratingCount">36
```

Какова причина того, что символы после пробела обрезаются?

Примечание: символов не всегда равное количество, бывает, что пробела в строке нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, пройдемся

```
(\w*)*
```

Две звезды необязательны, и, строго говоря, вы можете получить первым совпадением один символ. Или ноль символов.

```
(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(\w*)
```

Вот этот кусок имеет право совпасть ни с чем, что он, видимо и делает. Подозреваю, что если инвертировать жадность, то все взлетит. Но что точно можно было бы сделать:

- Регулярное выражение должно заканчиваться на начале следюущего тега, а не там, где оно захочет (как здесь)
- У нас должен быть как минимум один символ совпадения, а значит: `(\w*)(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(\w+)`
- Нам вообще не нужны три последовательные подмаски: `([\w]+(?:(?:\s|&nbsp;)\w+)*)`
- В конце концов, нас интересует, все содержимое тега: `\>([^\<]*)\<`

Теперь о подходе вообще.

Забудьте о парсинге HTML с помощью регулярок. Завтра у вас с этим совпадет `<div id="ratingCount">XX XX</div>`, но не совпадет `<span itemprop="ratingCount"> 32 32</span>`. Есть куча замечательных библиотек, чтобы работать с html, лично я использую symfony/dom-crawler.